# Writing a list to a text file?

Tags: list, text-files

I have made a list from a text file like this:

```
plain_text = open((input_filename), 'r')
characters = list(plain_text.read())
```

but I'm not able to do the reverse and write a list to a new text file. I have attempted to do it by using a for loop but get an error.

```
ciphertext = open('chipher text', 'w')   
for x in characters:
    ciphertext.write(characters[x])
```

The error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Why am I getting the error and what is the correct way to write a list to a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
output = ''.join(characters)
f = open('myfile','w')
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

**EDIT**
Writing to a file with encoding using codecs module

```
import codecs
output = ''.join(characters)
f = codecs.open("myfile", "w", "utf-8", "replace")
f.write(output)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this works when I do it in a separate file, but when I do it within my larger piece of code it creates an error. UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to <undefined> Any ideas why it might do this?